# positioning a taller image inside or "on top" of a smaller div

Tags: html, css, layout, positioning

I want to do something like this:

```
                                             ----------------   
                                             |              |
----------------------------------------------              ----------------
white background div                         | image on top |
----------------------------------------------              ----------------
                                             |              |
                                             ----------------
```

I want the image to be in the foreground so that it overlaps the div on the top and bottom ends.

What I already tried is absolute positioning by percentage values for `top` and `right` - but, as you know, all work's in vain when you resize the browser window..

Can someone help?

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r3yfm/)

Comment: post your code here please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

very easy to do!

Just add position: absolute; to your #content-header.

So your css looks like this:

```
#content-header {
    height: 4em;
    width: 100%;
    background: #000;
    color: #fff;
    position: absolute;
}
```

and then change the margin-top for #bubble.

So instead of top: 15%; take top: -75%;

It's -75% because -50% brings the middle of the img to the bottom of the header.
So you still have to place it a little bit more to the top. It's half the length you already did so that's why it's 75%

Your css will be like this for #bubble:

```
#bubble {
    height: 161px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 32%;
    top: -75%;
    width: 165px;
}
```

See the **[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r3yfm/15/)** i made.

Comment: What a shame I didn't notice this. It's still moving a little when narrowing the browser window, but as I said only a little. I plan to remove the image for the mobile version anyway. Thanks a lot

Comment: Well i can try to fix it, but if it's not really necessary i will leave it like this.

Comment: Of course, this will break if you change the height of the div or the image.

Comment: @StenPelzer In my case it's not necessary, as I'm going to hide that image on smaller screens. But IF you can fix that - why not. Much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Here you go if this is what you want

HTML

```
<div id="mainstrip"></div>
<div id="image">
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/ExLY1.jpg" width="100%" height="100%"/>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#mainstrip{
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
    height:20%;
    background-color: white;
    border: 2px solid black;
    top:10%;
    left:0;
}
#image{
    position:absolute;
    left:75%;
    top:0;
    width:15%;
    height:40%;
    z-index:100;
}
```

AND HERE IS A [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/8EMv4/) For your reference

Answer (score 0):

This example does not require any fixed pixel values for the height or width of the bar or image.

[**JSfiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Paulie_D/3PwKK/10/)

**HTML**

```
<div class="bar">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/food-q-c-200-200-5.jpg" alt=""/>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
body {
    background-color: grey;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.bar {
    margin-top: 200px;
    height:150px;
    background-color: white;
    position: relative;
}

.bar img {
    position: absolute;
    top:50%;
    left:50%;
    -webkit-transform:translate(-50%, -50%);   
}
```